# Paginating posts in a topic with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, kaminari

I'm having trouble paginating a topic's posts with Kaminari. The paginator partial shows up and seems to be calculating the number of pages it should have correctly, but all of the topic's posts are displayed on each page instead of the 2 posts I'm trying to get.

I have Topic and Post models, controllers, and views. A topic has_many posts, and a post belongs_to a topic.

I'm running Rails 4.

controllers/topics_controller

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  [snip]
  def show
    # Paginate
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @topic.posts.page(params[:page]).per(2)
  end
  [snip]
end
```

views/topics/show.html.erb

```
[snip other renders for header, breadcrumbs, etc.]

<%= render 'panel', :topic => @topic %>

[snip other renders]
```

views/topics/_panel.erb

```
<%= paginate @posts%>

[snip containing divs]
<h2><%= link_to topic.title, category_path(topic.id) %></h2>
<%= topic.description %>
[snip containing divs]

<%= render 'posts/posts', :topic => topic %>
```

posts/_posts.erb

```
<% for post in @topic.posts %>
    [snip table of post information]
<% end %>
```

Comment: `for post in @topic.posts` should be `for post in @posts`. Or better: `<%= render 'posts/posts', :topic => topic %>` => [`<%= render @posts %>`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections)

Comment: That fixed it, and I'm really upset. Thanks so much.